# Stuck while installing sample helloAndroid application in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

i m new to android,done with installing android, emulator is also gets started, but stuck somewhere ...

it says

```
[2012-01-25 12:28:22 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-01-25 12:28:22 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-25 12:28:22 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity activity launch
[2012-01-25 12:28:27 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-25 12:28:27 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
```

No success or failure message appears.
Do help, how to proceed further

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the emulator listed in the devices tab in the DDMS perspective?

I had a problem when it was not visible and the applications I built didn't show up in the emulator. I found this solution:

http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/android-disappearing-emulator-restart-adb-server/

I added the platform-tools path to the windows path and then simply type

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

in the command line. This makes the emulator appear in the devices list and I can subsequently debug my applications by pressing F11.

Comment: Hi PawelPredki

my emulator is listed in the DDMS perspective, will try again doing what you said, but the problem is still same, it says Installing HelloAndroid.apk.....

no Success or failure